# RXJS : How to unsubscribe the observable which doesn't have unsubscribe method in RxJs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created an `Observable` for listening to the `resize` event of the main `window` object which looks like this inside my component

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

    WindowListener$: Observable<event> = new fromEvent(window, 'resize');

    ngOnInit(): void{
        
         this.WindowListener$.subscribe(() => this.readWindowSize());
    }
}
```

All the `readWindowSize()` method does is read the height and width of the window and checks if they're larger than a certain size and toggles a boolean to `true` or `false` respectively.

Normally when I subscribe to something I unsubscribe to it in the `ngOnDestroy` hook but when I do this

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    
    this.WindowListener$.unsubscribe();

}
```

I get the red squiggly lines underneath `unsubscribe()`.  When I look through the available methods in the list that pops up after pressing `.` after the Observable name, I don't see any `unsubscribe()` method present in the list.  Unless I'm mistaking I've done this several times prior to Angular 16 to the point of making a habit of it.  Is there some other way I need to close the subscription?  Was there some update where it does it automatically now and they removed it?  I don't see why we'd be allowed to make a subscription while not having a way to close it down.  Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: not answer but it would be better to add `OnDestroy` like this: 
`export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {`

Comment: There are multiple ways which you can use to unsubscribe, some example are here
https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unsubscribe()` method is available on object returned by the subscribe method. Hence modified the code.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  WindowListener$: Observable<event> = new fromEvent(window, 'resize');
  private _windowsSubscription:Subscription
  ngOnInit(): void{
    this._windowsSubscription =  this.WindowListener$.subscribe(() => this.readWindowSize());
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    
    this._windowsSubscription.unsubscribe();

  }
}
```